# Juego del gato para cualquier dimensión del tablero

Tags: c

Hice el juego del gato, pero quiero saber como puede funcionar para cualquier dimensiones del tablero.

n la primer línea el valor  entero a buscar en el tablero.

En la segunda línea separados por un espacio, la cantidad 3<=n<=10 de renglones y columnas para una matriz (tablero) de forma cuadrada.

A partir de la tercera línea, se presentan separadas por un espacio los números de cada renglón de la matriz, se inicia con el renglón 0 y se termina con el renglon n-1 , y en cada renglón se inicia con la columna 0  y se termina con la columna . n-1

Se debe imprimir el número entero 1, si el valor  a buscar, se encuentra en todas las celdas de cualquier renglón, columna, diagonal principal o en la diagonal secundaria. Retorna 0 en otro caso.

ESTE ES MI CODIGO

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    
    char matriz[3][ 3], opc;
    int i, j;

    for(i=0; i<3; i++){
        for(j=0; j<3; j++){
            matriz[i][j]=' ';
            printf(" %c", matriz[i][j]);
         }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    int fila, col, ganador=0, turno=1;
    
        //para jugador 1
        do{
            if(turno%2==1){
                do{
                    scanf("%d", &fila);
                    scanf("%d", &col);
                    //ciclo para cuando el usuario ingrese coordenadas invalidas
                    if(matriz[fila][col] == 'x' || matriz[fila][col] == 'o' || fila > 2 || col > 2){
                    }
                }while(matriz[fila][col] == 'x' || matriz[fila][col] == 'o' || fila > 2 || col > 2);
                
                matriz[fila][col]='x';
                

                for(i=0; i<3; i++){
                    for(j=0; j<3; j++){
                        printf(" %c", matriz[i][j]);
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                }
                turno++;
                
            //para jugador dos
            } else if(turno%2==0){
                do{
                    scanf("%d", &fila);
                    scanf("%d", &col);
                    
                    //ciclo para cuando el usuario ingrese coordenadas invalidas
                    if(matriz[fila][col] == 'x' || matriz[fila][col] == 'o' || fila > 2 || col > 2){
                    }
                } while(matriz[fila][col] == 'x' || matriz[fila][col] == 'o' || fila > 2 || col > 2);
                
                matriz[fila][col]='o';
                
                
                for(i=0; i<3; i++){
                    for(j=0; j<3; j++){
                        printf(" %c", matriz[i][j]);
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                }
                turno++;
            }
            
            if(matriz[0][0] == 'x' && matriz[0][0] == matriz[0][1] && matriz[0][0] == matriz[0][2]
                || matriz[1][0] == 'x' && matriz[1][0] == matriz[1][1] && matriz[1][0] == matriz[1][2]
                    || matriz[2][0] == 'x' && matriz[2][0] == matriz[2][1] && matriz[2][0] == matriz[2][2]
                        
                        || matriz[0][0] == 'x' && matriz[0][0] == matriz[1][0] && matriz[0][0] == matriz[2][0]
                            || matriz[0][1] == 'x' && matriz[0][1] == matriz[1][1] && matriz[0][1] == matriz[2][1]
                                || matriz[0][2] == 'x' && matriz[0][2] == matriz[1][2] && matriz[0][2] == matriz[2][2]
                                    
                                    || matriz[0][0] == 'x' && matriz[0][0] == matriz[1][1] && matriz[0][0] == matriz[2][2]
                                        || matriz[0][2] == 'x' && matriz[0][2] == matriz[1][1] && matriz[0][2] == matriz[2][0]){
                ganador=1;
                printf("1\n");
            }
                                        
                                        if(matriz[0][0] == 'o' && matriz[0][0] == matriz[0][1] && matriz[0][0] == matriz[0][2]
                                            || matriz[1][0] == 'o' && matriz[1][0] == matriz[1][1] && matriz[1][0] == matriz[1][2]
                                                || matriz[2][0] == 'o' && matriz[2][0] == matriz[2][1] && matriz[2][0] == matriz[2][2]
                                                    
                                                    || matriz[0][0] == 'o' && matriz[0][0] == matriz[1][0] && matriz[0][0] == matriz[2][0]
                                                        || matriz[0][1] == 'o' && matriz[0][1] == matriz[1][1] && matriz[0][1] == matriz[2][1]
                                                            || matriz[0][2] == 'o' && matriz[0][2] == matriz[1][2] && matriz[0][2] == matriz[2][2]
                                                                
                                                                || matriz[0][0] == 'o' && matriz[0][0] == matriz[1][1] && matriz[0][0] == matriz[2][2]
                                                                    || matriz[0][2] == 'o' && matriz[0][2] == matriz[1][1] && matriz[0][2] == matriz[2][0]){
                                            ganador=1;
                                            printf(" 2\n");
                                        }
                                                                    
        } while(ganador != 1);
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Y qué problema tiene tu código?

Comment: que solo funciona para matrices de 3 x 3 pero quiero saber como hacer para que funcione para una matriz de 4X4 o 10X10

Comment: Vale. Probaste alguna aproximación para intentar que funcione en ese escenario?

Comment: Bueno.. yo no se como es el juego ese.. pero tu codigo primero esta escrito solo para 3 porque dimensiona un array de 3... y luego hace comprobaciones basandose en que hay 3... en los if.. entonces todo eso habria que reescribirlo...

Comment: Señor, se acada de encontrar con el gran problema de los numeros magicos. Eso no se hace. Si un numero se repite, lo conviertes en una constate. Por no hacer eso te costara mas modificar este codigo.

Comment: De igual forma hay mucho código repetido, recomiendo que utilices funciones

Answer (score 2):

Para una solución general lo primero es definir la dimensión de la matriz y usar esa definición de ahí en adelante (no el número pelado):

```
#define DIM 4
#define VACIA '+'
```

La forma general del programa es:

```
int main() {
    int ganador = 0;
    int turno = 1;
    char matriz[DIM][DIM];

    matriz_zero(matriz);
    imprimir_matriz(matriz);

    while (!ganador) {
        if (turno) {
            ganador = pedir_celda(matriz, 'x');
        } else {
            ganador = pedir_celda(matriz, '0');
        }
        turno = !turno;
    }
    printf("Ganaste!!!");
    return 0;
}
```

La estructura general del programa es:

- Inicializar la matriz.
- Entrar en un ciclo hasta que haya un ganador:
- En cada iteración, por turnos pedir una jugada, validarla y evaluarla.
- Si ya tenemos un ganador, terminar.
- En caso contrario, cambiar de turno y repetir el ciclo.

Para todo esto nos apoyamos con funciones. La más importante es `pedir_celda`. Esta pide las coordenadas, revisa que estén dentro de los límites y que la celda esté desocupada. Si no, vuelve a pedir los datos.

Luego de aceptar coordenadas válidas, marca la celda y luego revisa la matriz para ver si hay un ganador.

```
int pedir_celda(char m[DIM][DIM], char marca) {
    //  Pide una celda, valida que este vacia, la llena y revisa si es un ganador.
    int fila, col;
    while (1) {
        printf("--- Jugador %c ---\n", marca);
        printf("> fila: ");
        scanf("%d", &fila);
        printf("> columna: ");
        scanf("%d", &col);

        if (fila >= 0 && fila < DIM && col >= 0 && col < DIM) {
            if (m[fila][col] == VACIA) {
                m[fila][col] = marca;
                imprimir_matriz(m);
                break;
            } else {
                printf("Celda está ocupada\n");
            }
        } else {
            printf("Coordenadas fuera de rango\n");
        }
    }

    return revisar_ganador(m, fila, col);
}
```

La función `revisar_ganador` revisa si la pieza recién puesta en (fila, col) completa el juego. Para eso revisa por fila, por columna y por ambas diagonales:

```
int revisar_ganador(char m[DIM][DIM], int fila, int col) {
    //  Revisa el jugador en la celda (fila, col) ha completado
    //  las celdas requeridas
    
    // Todas las celdas deben tener el mismo valor que (fila, col)
    char marca = m[fila][col];
    int i;

    //  Recorrer la misma fila contando las celdas iguales.
    for (i = 0; i < DIM; i++) {
        if (m[fila][i] != marca)
            break;
    }
    if (i == DIM) {
        return 1;
    }

    //  Recorrer la misma columna contando las celdas iguales.
    for (i = 0; i < DIM; i++) {
        if (m[fila][i] != marca)
            break;
    }
    if (i == DIM) {
        return 1;
    }

    //  Recorrer las diagonales
    return revisar_diagonales(m);
}
```

El problema de revisar las diagonales se simplifica si consideramos que sólo hay dos diagonales máximas donde se puede completar la cantidad de celdas requeridas:

```
int revisar_diagonales(char m[DIM][DIM]) {
    //  Revisa si alguna de las dos diagonales maximas esta totalmente
    //  llena con la misma marca.
    //  Retorna True en tal caso.    
    int en_linea = 0;
    char marca = m[0][0];
    int count = 0;
    for (int fila = 0; fila < DIM; fila++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < DIM; col++) {
            if (m[fila][col] == marca)
                count++;
        }
    }
    if (count != DIM) {
        marca = m[0][DIM - 1];
        count = 0;
        for (int fila = 0; fila < DIM; fila++) {
            for (int col = DIM - 1; col >= 0; col--) {
                if (m[fila][col] == marca)
                    count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return (count == DIM);
}
```

Y luego las funciones de apoyo para redondear la solución:

```
void imprimir_matriz(char m[DIM][DIM]) {
    //  Imprime la matriz.
    for (int i = 0; i < DIM; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < DIM; j++) {
            printf(" %c", m[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void matriz_zero(char m[DIM][DIM]) {
    //  Inicializa las celdas con el caracter VACIA
    for (int i = 0; i < DIM; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < DIM; j++) {
            m[i][j] = VACIA;
        }
    }
}
```